# How do I find repeated names in dataset and put them in separate column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of Titanic passengers. Suppose passengers' full names are listed in the column 'Name'. There are spouses, siblings, parents, children on board. Apparently, they have the same last name in the column 'Name'.

I filtered out the last name as:

```
dt['LastName'] = dt['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
```

The problem is to filter the data (supposedly using apply function along axis = 0) where the last names of the passengers match, so that to get a new column 'Relatives'.

At the end it would be nice to have a new table with two columns: a passenger's name and name of the relatives on board.

Comment: Your approach would assume that the last names are unique, that is that all individuals on the boat carrying the same last name are spouses or sibblings. That cannot be true, especially for member of the third class. The you can do is make estimations: I suggest you look at this https://www.kaggle.com/ailuropus/extracting-family-relationships-on-titanic-sibsp

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes thank you! In this specific problem we were told to assume all people with the same last name were family members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me share the answer.

```
dt['LastName'] = dt['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
```

The first step is to merge two columns of the table with respect to the last name, filtered earlier, using method 'merge'.

```
merged_data = pd.merge(
left = dt[['LastName', 'Name']],
right = dt[['LastName', 'Name']],
on = "LastName",
how = 'inner')
```

Since the column last name is not required, it can be dropped with the help of the method 'drop':

```
 merged_data.drop(['LastName'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Columns can be renamed with the corresponding method 'rename':

```
 merged_data.rename(columns = {
'Name_x': 'FamilyMember',
'Name_y':'Relative'},
inplace = True)
```

Finally, to eliminate the rows where the name corresponds to itself we apply the filter:

```
merged_data = merged_data[merged_data['FamilyMember'] != merged_data['Relative']]
```